# How to stop music when clicking to new activity and be able to start it again from the beginning?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I have an audio playing in the background when I am clicking onto a new activity. I want while I am clicking to the next activity, for the audio, to stop.

However, when going back to the original activity I want the audio to start again from the beginning.

Using media player and Android Studio. Here's all the media player code I have so far:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(pagetwo.this,R.raw.audio1);
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic lifecycle methods of your Activity to handle this use case:

Android will call onPause() if you open a new Activity and will call onResume() if you enter/come back to the first activity.

If you call mediaPlayer.start() in onResume() and mediaPlayer.stop() in onPause() you should have the desired behavior.